# Google Maps Error. API? ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google

Tags: google-maps

I am encountering some issues with the google maps component of a site.

I understand there has been recent changes to the use of maps and have generated an API key to use on the site.

The map is displaying fine on the idex.html page but displays error..
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: google
on the other two pages?

I am really in out of my depth with these type of things and appreciate any support that may be offered. The site is live at [maverickonthebay.com.au](http://mavericksonthebay.com.au)

Answer (score 0):

I check the page([url](http://mavericksonthebay.com.au/functions.html)),

I guess you need to remove the `defer` attribute from the google-maps-api load script tag.

Because the code is minify, is hard to check whats wrong and why.

Comment: Hey thanks, what does minify mean?  Its weird, If I refresh the page the map is there. There is also another error in the console stating: InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function :(

Comment: *minify* means you trying to remove all the space and simplify the variables, like your costom.min.js. When you refresh the page, the google maps api is cached in your browser, so it will execute initMap() immediately, but I think you write function initMap() in somewhere else, if you didn't, remove `callback=initMap` attribute in script tag.